# Boost::Asio fail create thread for async_connect

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, boost, pthreads

I have an issue with the function async_connect of Boost::Asio.

I have an application which can run in 2 modes, client and server. I use TCP socket from boost Asio.
When I compile on Linux, everything work fine, I can run client and server and connect each together. But, when I cross compile on 
windows with MinGW, the client crash on the async_connect(). Here is the error message logged from try..catch on windows 7 :

> thread: The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced

So, I have some clues :

I use pthread instead of Boost.Thread to run io_service::run(). I Have multiple engines running in different threads created with pthread and work fine on both windows and linux. So, I want run the io_service with pthread too.

If I use Boost.Thread only for run io_service, I got an error on the compile :

> boost/config/requires_threads.hpp:29:4: error: #error "Threading support unavaliable: it has been explicitly disabled with BOOST_DISABLE_THREADS"

I found in the [official documentation](http://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_5_3/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/implementation.html) for Windows platform :

> An additional thread per io_service is used for the select demultiplexing. This thread is created on the first call to async_connect().

My application crash on the call of async_connect, so I think Boost can't create thread with pthread or something like that.

I tryied differents #define, but nothing work, and I'm not sure I understand all of them :

```
-D _WIN32_WINNT=0x0601
-D BOOST_USE_WINDOWS_H 
-D BOOST_WINDOWS
-D WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
-D BOOST_HAS_PTHREADS
-D BOOST_HAS_THREADS
```

here is my async_connect function :

```
socket.async_connect(_ep,boost::bind(&tcp_client::handle_connect,this,new_connection,boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

Comment: Did you compile the Boost libraries yourself? If not, what build did you use?

Comment: Yes, I build boost 1.49 with i686-w64-minGW last official binary. Actually, I use connect() wich is a synchrone connection and work well. But I'm curious to know how thread creation fail...